# Как передавать делегаты в качестве аргументов функций

Tags: c#

Есть код: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49548/Industrial-NET-PID-Controllers.

Для доступа к параметрам используются делегаты:

```
namespace PIDLibrary
{
    public delegate double GetDouble();
    public delegate void SetDouble(double value);
}
```

Начальные значения параметров передаются через конструктор:

```
 public PID(double pG, double iG, double dG,
        double pMax, double pMin, double oMax, double oMin,
        GetDouble pvFunc, GetDouble spFunc, SetDouble outFunc)
```

Что необходимо передать в аргументах конструктора на месте вопросительных знаков?

```
PID pid = new PID(double, double, double, double..., ?, ?, ?);
```

Comment: А где тут C++ в вашем вопросе?

Comment: @VladD, уже исправил.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

У вас должны быть реализованы функции, соответствующие сигнатурам делегатов, либо  лямбда-функции.

**Первый вариант**. Ваш код по созданию объекта PID вызывается в методе некого класса, добавьте в этот класс методы для получения/записи значений:

```
private double GetPV()
{
    /* возвращаете некое число типа double */
    // return ...;
}

private double GetSP()
{
    /* возвращаете некое число типа double */
    // return ...;
}

private void WriteOV(double value)
{
    /* используете здесь значение value */
}
```

И подставляете их в конструктор PID:

```
PID pid = new PID(..., GetPV, GetSP, WriteOV);
```

**Второй вариант**. Необходимо создать лямбда функции с подходящими сигнатурами:

```
GetDouble pvFunc = () => /* возвращаете некое число типа double */;
GetDouble spFunc = () => /* возвращаете некое число типа double */;
SetDouble outFunc = value => {
    /* используете значение value */
};

PID pid = new PID(..., pvFunc, spFunc, outFunc);
```

Какой из вариантов удобнее использовать, зависит от контекста.